# How to save the iterated row record to new data frame or list while looping, using Spark SQL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have one data frame. That data frame is giving me list of records and then I am going to iterate over each row and doing some manipulation.

```
 for (row <- dataframe.rdd.collect()) {

// var anyval= row.mkString(",").split(",")(take the column);
}
```

Then I am Making some checks and then if current row will match the requirement then try to create new list or collection to save full row .

Could you please help to with example how to save this row in new data frame using spark sql?

Comment: vae a look at withColumn and remain within dataframe scope

Comment: No need for collect

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achieve this, the main point is understand the basic behavior main components of `spark`.
For all of them (`dataframe`, `dataset`, `rdd`) you can not update the actual value, they are inmutable objects, but you can iterate their items and based on your logic, create a new one, based on an existing one. Examples:

```
val yourDF = Seq( // Sample
  ("A1", 12, null),       // Record 1
  ("B1", -1, "Mexico"),   // Record 2
  ("C1", 2, "Argentina")  // Record 3
).toDF("id", "some_value", "country") // Column definition

yourDF.show() // Visualize your DF
```

Above code will output:

```
+---+----------+---------+
| id|some_value|  country|
+---+----------+---------+
| A1|        12|     null|
| B1|        -1|   Mexico|
| C1|         2|Argentina|
+---+----------+---------+
```

Based on that is a `Dataframe`, this is how you can iterate all rows and access their items:

```
val newDF = yourDF
  .map(item =>{  // Iterate your DF 
    val id = item.getAs[String]("id") // Access their element (from row object - each item in your DF) - You need to specify datatype and 'column_name' on this approach
    val some_value = item.getAs[Integer]("some_value")
    val country = item.getAs[String]("country")
    val outputCountry = if(country != null) country.substring(0,3) else null
    // Output: id, first 3 chars of the country (if it is not null) and `some_value` multiplied by 10
    (id, outputCountry, some_value*10)
  })

newDF.show()
```

Above code will output:

```
+---+----+---+
| _1|  _2| _3|
+---+----+---+
| A1|null|120|
| B1| Mex|-10|
| C1| Arg| 20|
+---+----+---+
```

As you can see, column names are not the same as the first `DF`, this is because we are creating a new one and we did not specify the column names, we can use either `.toDF("column_a", "column_b", "column_c")` or use a case class like in the next example.

Let's do same exercise, but using `case classes` (with `Scala`).

```
case class Country(id: String, some_value: Integer, country: String) // Case class

val newDF = yourDF
  .as[Country] // Cast your DF with a case class to have a Dataset
  .map(country=>{ // iterate dataset
    val id = country.id // Access their element (as object notation, easier!)
    val some_value = country.some_value
    val countryName = country.country
    val outputCountry = if(countryName != null) countryName.substring(0,3) else null
    // Output: id, first 3 chars of the country (if it is not null) and `some_value` multiplied by 10
    Country(id, some_value*10, outputCountry) // Output will use a case class to define the schema of the new object (DAtaset[Country])
  })

newDF.show()
```

Above code will output:

```
+---+----------+-------+
| id|some_value|country|
+---+----------+-------+
| A1|       120|   null|
| B1|       -10|    Mex|
| C1|        20|    Arg|
+---+----------+-------+
```